# Compact all migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple migrations:

1. .....
2. create table
3. add column
4. add another column
5. remove other column
   6 .....

Is there any ablity to change all these migrations to one new migration which will create the same database schema?

Comment: you mean the same schema for just this particular table? Because there is `schema.rb` in your `db` folder, which is actually your database big migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can change remove those migrations and create a new one, called for example "initial_schema", where you should put the content of the schema.rb composed by all your previous migrations.

Consider that rails generate a schema.rb for you when you run those migrations.

Then you need to drop all tables in your database and run again **rake db:migrate**.